# LTspice unknown subcircuit called OnSemi MOSFET

Tags: ltspice

I have a problem with [importing spice models from OnSemi.](https://www.onsemi.com/design/resources/design-resources/models?rpn=NTMFS5H600NL)

I have tried several interesting MOSFET libs from OnSemi, but I always get the same issue:

[image]

I extract the lib and put the symbol and the lib in the same directory as the ".asc" file.

I have also tried to include the lib in the schematic, but the issue remains the same.

Any ideas how to use MOSFET libs from OnSemi? Are their libs just broken?

Comment: [Works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtYfZ.png) for me. You probably have a typo.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen seems like that was the issue, apperently I hade to have high letters in the .lib include to match exactly it seemed like

Comment: There's nothing "apparently" about it, it's *precisely*. The program can't search for fuzzy criteria, or even read minds. :-)